# Visual Studio Stops, Goes To Debug Mode, But I Don't Know Which Line It Is Paused At

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a strange problem with Visual Studio.  I imported an existing project into a solution and now when I run it, it stops running and goes into debug mode.  The problem is that while in debug mode, there's no yellow highlighted line indicating where the code has stopped.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click in any code window and choose *Show Next Statement* - this should magically take you there!

Comment: I just tried Show Next Statement, and it doesn't show me the next statment (it just stays in the same window).

Comment: Do you have any other instances of VS in debug mode at the same time?

Comment: Barrylloyd, I had other instances of VS open, none in debug mode, but after closing those, my program worked fine.  Thanks for helping me out! :D

Comment: I also often have the strange problem that my application wont start when having a second visual studio instance open. Strange, strange.

Answer (score 3):

Go to **Debug->Windows->Call Stack** and double click on the top line in Call Stack window.

Comment: SKINDER, that helps, but now I have another question.  
In the Call Stack, it says I'm stuck in program.cs, in the line:

Application.Run(new MyForm());

Unfortunately, it doesn't say which line inside of MyForm() my code is hanging on.

Answer (score 0):

Is the stack trace window up?  That should show where you're paused too.